# JavaScript tag with rocket property

Tags: javascript, html

In the site: pro emoji keyboard online at http://www.emojiselector.com, I saw in source code, something as follows:

```
<script data-rocketsrc="assets/web/assets/jquery/jquery.min.js" type="text/rocketscript"></script>
<script data-rocketsrc="assets/tether/tether.min.js" type="text/rocketscript"></script>
```

What does this mean? data-rocketsrc, text/rocketscript??? I know for traditional tag in html is src and text/javascript. Is this another languages or another standards? I saw in code of JS, nothing is different!

Answer (score 1):

HTML tags can contain custom attributes. These can be useful for implementing application-specific features. See ["Using data attributes"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) over at MDN for more information.

Answer (score 0):

> Rocket Loader is a general-purpose asynchronous JavaScript loader coupled with a lightweight virtual browser which can safely run any JavaScript code after window.onload.
>
> Turning on Rocket Loader will almost always immediately improve a web page's window.onload time (assuming there is JavaScript on the page).

Comment: It seems that this answer is copied and pasted from somewhere. Can you add a link to the source, Srikrushna Pal? You can update your answer by clicking on the **[edit]** link under the post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your website seems to be powered by [CloudFlare](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us). CloudFlare uses Rocket Loader to speed up the website loading speed. Read more [here](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168056-What-does-Rocket-Loader-do-).